# django/python the works of views and bringing in an API

Tags: python, django, api, django-views

I'm just beginning to learn about python/django. I know PHP, but I wanted to get to know about this framework. I'm trying to work with yelp's API. I'm trying to figure out what to do when someone brings in a new file into the project.

In their `business.py` they have this:

```
import json
import oauth2
import optparse
import urllib
import urllib2

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-c', '--consumer_key', dest='consumer_key', help='OAuth consumer key (REQUIRED)')
parser.add_option('-s', '--consumer_secret', dest='consumer_secret', help='OAuth consumer secret (REQUIRED)')
parser.add_option('-t', '--token', dest='token', help='OAuth token (REQUIRED)')
parser.add_option('-e', '--token_secret', dest='token_secret', help='OAuth token secret (REQUIRED)')
parser.add_option('-a', '--host', dest='host', help='Host', default='api.yelp.com')
parser.add_option('-i', '--id', dest='id', help='Business')
parser.add_option('-u', '--cc', dest='cc', help='Country code')
parser.add_option('-n', '--lang', dest='lang', help='Language code')


options, args = parser.parse_args()

# Required options
if not options.consumer_key:
  parser.error('--consumer_key required')
if not options.consumer_secret:
  parser.error('--consumer_secret required')
if not options.token:
  parser.error('--token required')
if not options.token_secret:
  parser.error('--token_secret required')

if not options.id:
  parser.error('--id required')

url_params = {}
if options.cc:
  url_params['cc'] = options.cc
if options.lang:
  url_params['lang'] = options.lang


path = '/v2/business/%s' % (options.id,)


def request(host, path, url_params, consumer_key, consumer_secret, token, token_secret):
  """Returns response for API request."""
  # Unsigned URL
  encoded_params = ''
  if url_params:
    encoded_params = urllib.urlencode(url_params)
  url = 'http://%s%s?%s' % (host, path, encoded_params)
  print 'URL: %s' % (url,)

  # Sign the URL
  consumer = oauth2.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
  oauth_request = oauth2.Request('GET', url, {})
  oauth_request.update({'oauth_nonce': oauth2.generate_nonce(),
                        'oauth_timestamp': oauth2.generate_timestamp(),
                        'oauth_token': token,
                        'oauth_consumer_key': consumer_key})

  token = oauth2.Token(token, token_secret)
  oauth_request.sign_request(oauth2.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), consumer, token)
  signed_url = oauth_request.to_url()
  print 'Signed URL: %s\n' % (signed_url,)

  # Connect
  try:
    conn = urllib2.urlopen(signed_url, None)
    try:
      response = json.loads(conn.read())
    finally:
      conn.close()
  except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
    response = json.loads(error.read())

  return response

response = request(options.host, path, url_params, options.consumer_key, options.consumer_secret, options.token, options.token_secret)
print json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
```

Its very lengthy, I appologize for that. But my concern is what do I do with this? They've set up a `def request()` in here, and I'm assuming that I have to import this into my views?

I've been following the django documentation of creating a new app. In the documentation they've set up a bunch of `def` inside the `views.py` file. I'm just confused as to how am I supposed to make this work with my project? If I wanted to search for a business in the URL, how would it send the data out?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a script, not a usable module.  The logic is there, but you need to do some re-organization to get this into a usable state for django (unless you shell out with a subprocess or something - not recommended)

Comment: This function is entirely independent of Django. Learn how to make a Django application first (perhaps one that presents mock data instead of real Yelp data). At that point, how to use this function should be clear to you

Comment: @sberry So typically if they give you a script, I just take some of their scripts out and reorganize it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a command line script that makes http requests to the yelp api. You probably don't want to make such an external request within the context of a main request handler. Well, you could call a request handler that makes this call to yelp. Let's see ...

You could import the request function and instead of invoking it with command line options, call it yourself.

```
from yelp.business import request as yelp_req

def my_request_handler(request):
    json_from_yelp = yelp_req(...
    # do stuff and return a response
```

Making this kind of external call inside a request handler is pretty meh though (that is, making an http request to an external service within a request handler). If the call is in ajax, it may be ok for the ux.

This business.py is just an example showing you how to create a signed request with oauth2. You may be able to just import the request function and use it. OTOH, you may prefer to write your own (perhaps using the `requests` library). You probably want to use celery or some other async means to make the calls outside of your request handlers and/or cache the responses to avoid costly external http io with every request.

Comment: how come you don't prefer importing the file out of the box like the example you just did?

Comment: not sure what you mean "importing the file out of the box", pls explain.

Comment: i mean from your example. If I just download the files from github, and just put it into `mysite`, why don't you prefer doing the `from yelp.business import request as yelp_req`? Do you prefer to just use their file as reference and write your own code into the `view.py`?

Comment: the request function is the only bit that is reusable, the rest of the script is dealing with command-line parameters with `optparse`. Realistically, you might just use this function as a starting point to write your own calls to yelp; but, you may be able to just use the function as is.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the help! Do you know where to put the consumer key, consumer secret, etc..? Is it supposed to be in the `dest=`?

Comment: `dest` tells optparse where to put the variable when run from the CL. In Django, you'll probably want to put the keys in BASH variables and/or settings.